# open bootstrap modal with different id

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I upload example for my problem:

I have number of button. each one ofen the same bootstrap modal, but with different id (send via $_GET).

inside the modal i have form with scrip for uploading images.

for some reason the modal show the same id while it actually should be different according the button you click. the first ID that was sent to the modal will be the same for the rest of the buttons.

http://80.179.226.44/~israelig/sites/exmytrip/tempFile.php

if i remove the jquery.js inside the modal, the right id is shown, but the upload files script doesn't works.
example: 
http://80.179.226.44/~israelig/sites/exmytrip/tempFile2.php

how can it be fixed?

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: @FrankerZ  - that's way i made the demo...

Comment: See [mcve]. Post the code here, as if your site goes down in the future, it will not be able to help future readers.

Comment: Its demo not the code. How can anyone determine the code from demo??

Comment: I removed all the code that is not important for this issue and create lite code, so that you won't need to review lots of none-important texts